# How do I return an arbitrary array with the same size as an argument in Rust?

Tags: arrays, function, rust, return

I want to write a function that takes an array as an input and returns a new array with each value doubled. Since the size of the returned array depends on the array given as a parameter, its size cant be known at compile time.

How can I return an array with an unknown size? The code could look similar to this:

```
fn double_array(arr: &[i32]) -> &[i32] { /* ... */ }
```

Inside I would use an anonymous function in combination with `map` to do the actual work.

I know that this functions is useless since I could just do the same in the place I need it, and that I should use generics instead of `i32` - but this is just for me to understand the language.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=75e139c5598466ffc78e0f595d6dc15f)

Comment: @Shepmaster I dont understand how the other question applies to my question - I dont see any arrays being returned and they speak about features that will be implemented in the future - does that mean returning an array of unknown size is not possible right now?

Comment: correct, it’s not possible in stable Rust 1.36. You can’t define an array that will have a fixed length without hard coding that length in the type. It doesn’t matter that you want to accept or return it from a function if it cannot be represented in the type system.

Comment: Make sure you refresh yourself on the differences between an *array*, a *slice*, and a *`Vec`*. These are all different in Rust and can be used in similar but different manners.